# How to access app:headerLayout (axml) inside Activity? Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a question about how to access headerLayout. So I want to call a variable contained in Layout drawerheaderlayout.axml, so it can be inserted into an activity (variable).

This is my code as well as the information I want to know.

**Main.axml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:menu="@menu/navmenu"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/headerdrawerlayout" /><!--this header-->
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**drawerheaderlayout.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="178dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="@drawable/imgBg">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/callUsername"<!--I want to call this variable inside Activity-->
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the `NavigationView` first in the `MainActivity`. Then use `GetHeaderView()` method to get `drawerheaderlayout`. Finally use `FindViewById()` to get the textview.

For example:

```
        NavigationView navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
        navigationView.SetNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        View header = navigationView.GetHeaderView(0);
        /*View view=navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);*/
        TextView name = (TextView)header.FindViewById(Resource.Id.callUsername);
```

Comment: Hey Billy, thank you for your response. I like your reference :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do : 
First, I create an AppCompatActivity for the drawer layout, on the main activity, it refer to the AppCompatActivity.

DrawerLayout Activity :

```
public class DrawerLayout : AppCompatActivity
{
TextView UserName;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.drawerheaderlayout);
    UserName = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.callUsername) // here you call your username

}

}
```

Main Activity :

```
public class MainView : DrawerLayout
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FrameLayout contentFrameLayout = FindViewById<FrameLayout>(Resource.Id.content_frame);
    LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Main, contentFrameLayout); // here I Inflate the main.axml
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the response Vincent,
From what I see based on your answer, I conclude that should make 2 Activity.

From what I made above, actually I want to try to create a navigation drawer that contains headerLayout (later will be called on the database like user image, user name, etc). Therefore I need 1 activity to call the navigation drawer on some layout which will be called based on the variable.